# ArcObjects- IBorder.GetGeometry() in Python

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-desktop, geometry

I am trying to get geometry of frame border trough IFrameElement.Border. I do receive IBorder object, which has .GetGeometry() method.

How do I use this method to get geometry of the border?

I can not find code snippet in any language, so any advice where to look for is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Public Sub Test()
    ' Get polygon of map frame border
    Dim pMXD As IMxDocument
    Set pMXD = ThisDocument
    Dim pPageLayout As IPageLayout
    Set pPageLayout = pMXD.PageLayout
    Dim pMap As IMap
    Set pMap = pMXD.FocusMap
    Dim pDisplay As IDisplay
    Set pDisplay = pMXD.ActiveView.ScreenDisplay
    Dim pGraphicsContainer As IGraphicsContainer
    Set pGraphicsContainer = pPageLayout
    Dim pFrameElement As IFrameElement
    Set pFrameElement = pGraphicsContainer.FindFrame(pMap)
    Dim pMapFrame As IMapFrame
    Set pMapFrame = pFrameElement
    Dim pBorder As IBorder
    Set pBorder = pMapFrame.Border
    Dim pPolygon As IPolygon
    Dim pE As IElement
    Set pE = pMapFrame
    Set pPolygon = pBorder.GetGeometry(pDisplay, pE.Geometry)

    ' Add pPolygon back to page layout using default symbology
    Dim pPolygonElement As IPolygonElement
    Set pPolygonElement = New PolygonElement
    Dim pElement As IElement
    Set pElement = pPolygonElement
    pElement.Geometry = pPolygon
    pGraphicsContainer.AddElement pElement, 0
    pMXD.ActiveView.PartialRefresh esriViewGraphics, Nothing, Nothing
End Sub
```